# Create an intervals' column in R using quantiles and compute an average after that

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, intervals

I have a dataset like that, representing contracts [invented data here due to confidentiality] :

| field | subgroup | duration_days | amount_per_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72145 | 7214598 | 700 | 8095800.2 |
| 72145 | 7214598 | 541 | 5039689.1 |
| 72145 | 7214554 | 98 | 3801372.8 |
| 72145 | 7214554 | 900 | 2444928.7 |
| 90385 | 9038529 | 100 | 2861857.0 |
| 90385 | 9038529 | 284 | 1736789.4 |

I'd like to obtain 2 other columns : one concerning intervals of days, based on 33th and 66th quantiles, and another that compute the average amount per day grouped by field and subgroup.

**Desired output**

| field | subgroup | days_intervals | avg_amount_per_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72145 | 7214598 | 0-33th quantile | Value1 |
| 72145 | 7214598 | 33th-66th quantile | Value2 |
| 72145 | 7214598 | 66th quantile - (duration of the longest contract) | Value3 |

And so on for all the field and subgroup, with of course Value 1,2,3 that are numbers as well as the values of quantiles.

When i use the following code :

```
f <- data.frame(df %>%  dplyr::group_by(field, subgroup) %>% dplyr::summarize(quants = quantile(duration_days, probs = c(0.33, 0.66))))
```

I obtain a dataframe with 3 columns : field, subgroup, quants, with 1 row per grouping and quantile value (so 2 rows everytime).

I'm wondering if R is a good tool to do that, but i can use Python if it's easier for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take help of `cut` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  
  group_by(field, subgroup) %>%
  group_by(quants = cut(duration_days, quantile(duration_days, c(0, .33, .66, 1)), 
                        labels = c('33%', '66%', '100%'), include.lowest = TRUE), .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(avg_amount_per_day = mean(amount_per_day, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```